# form submit not work in django project (python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have registration form and one submit button. when you click submit, if there is an error the height of the div increases so I do auto = "height". but now submit button not work when i submit I do not fill out the inputs, it does not show anything.the submit button inside form. how fix?

this is my code --->

script.js

```
function changeSize(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = document.querySelector(".continer");
    el.style.height = "auto";

}
```

home.html **(submit code)**

```
<button type="submit" name="register" id="btn" onClick = "changeSize(event)">registration</button>
```

Comment: I think is the event.preventDefault();...try removed.

Comment: Are you sure that class name for you are running `querySelector()` is `continer`?

Comment: @dewDevil yes i am sure.

Comment: Try giving `return false` from the function.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova when i remove preventDefault() and when i submit button click continer css change but after 1 second return same size. i want to increase the size of the main div (.continer)  if there are errors when pressing the button

Comment: @dewDevil i tried but don't show erros

Comment: @dewDevil I want the continer size to become auto in case of errors and not return to the same size after 1 second

Comment: Yes I understand, but if you remove it works the submit, I'm right? Look at API doc. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova yes work. show errors and continer size is auto but after one second .continer return same size (400px) that is, it is no longer auto

Comment: Ok, you must consider always the submit must work, that's the point, now you want keep it nice and pretty, so to help you, share more code and we can help you in one solution. Sometimes we can use one hack to workaround this kind of behaviour like setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 300);, did you try?

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova I have not tried. Can you tell me how and where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Input the following code in your function:

```
$('#form-id').submit()
```

This will make sure the form will submit after all the changes you are doing to the container.

Comment: how? function changeSize() {
    var el = document.querySelector(".continer").setAttribute("style", "height:auto");
    $('#reg').submit()


}

Comment: I usually like to bind to an onclick: `$('#btn).on('click, function(e) {e.preventDefault(); var el = document.querySelector(".continer").setAttribute("style", "height:auto"); $('#reg').submit() }`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: There is a parenthesis missing after the submit, before the end curly braces. I recommend you debug those small things yourself.